# Using both fixed-width and variable-width font in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, fonts

I would like to have an org-mode file with the following content:

```
#+TITLE: My awesome Emacs file

* My Header
Here's some information under the header

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo "this is some code"
#+END_SRC

More text and =verbatim= things
```

Is it possible to have Emacs display the header and text in a variable-width font and only the `#+BEGIN_SRC`, `#+END_SRC`, `=verbatim=` and source code in a fixed-width font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all-but-a-dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3758139) on SO.  As of this writing, the accepted answer over there is (mutatis mutandis):

`(set-face-attribute 'org-verbatim nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)`

EDIT: Actually read your question.  Since you want to change multiple faces, this is a more complete answer:

```
(dolist (face '(org-block-begin-line 
                org-block-end-line 
                org-verbatim 
                org-block-background))
  (set-face-attribute face nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
```

Note that this will overwrite any existing `:inherit` parameters on the faces.  If that's a problem, another answer to the same SO question provides code to work around the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package for precisely that: [mixed-pitch](https://gitlab.com/jabranham/mixed-pitch) mode.

Comment: Thank you — this is perfect and solves all the issues I've hit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with how `org-mode` delimits blocks, so I can only give a general answer.

There is a standard face called `variable-pitch`, which you can apply to a given region like this:

```
(set-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(face (variable-pitch))))
```

This only works when automatic fontification is inhibited, though.  You may be able to hook into `org-mode`'s fontification code and override the face of selected regions with `variable-pitch`.